# Is there a way to perform animation on specific mesh in 3d model

Tags: aframe

I am loading 3D model on marker using a-frame.Once my model is loaded,I want to perform animation(changing the positioning of the mesh slowly) on a specific mesh of a 3D Model.how can I achieve that.

I am posting the code.
Here in this code iam accessing specific mesh of 3D model,to that mesh i am setting an attribute 'Animation'(is this a correct approach).
[Glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/glorious-brash-frown?path=index.html%3A3%3A8)

```js
el.addEventListener("model-loaded", e =>{
                    let tree3D = el.getObject3D('mesh');
                    if (!tree3D){return;}    
                  console.log('tree3D', tree3D);
                    tree3D.traverse(function(node){
                        if (node.isMesh){   
                          console.log(node);
                            if(node.name == "Trunk_A")
                              {
                                var trunkA_mesh=tree3D.getObjectByName('Trunk_A')
                                trunkA_mesh.setAttribute('animation','property:position;to :0 4 0;dur:500');
                                
                              }
                        }
                    });
              });
```

[image: error]

Comment: It is better to post errors and code as (code formatted) text rather than screen captures :)

Comment: I have posted my code there.

Comment: It will be more complicated than that. Components are meant to be used on DOM elements. the mesh is a 3D object, so you cannot use the animation attribute as you would on an html entity. You could get some inspiration on animation component source code to achieve what you're trying to do. https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/blob/master/components/animation/index.js but it's not trivial :)